# Send click inside VSFlexGrid window using the WinAPI

Tags: excel

Does anyone know if it is possible to send a click to a line within a VSFlexGrid window using the WinAPI, any help reference would be greatly appreciated.
I used VBA but no luck.
[image]

I used vba but No luck